# crytpojs and openssl - diffrent aes outputs

Tags: javascript, php, openssl, cryptography, cryptojs

I'm trying to get the same AES encryption output in PHP an Javascript

PHP code:

```
<?php
$rawKey = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
$iv = substr($rawKey, 16, 16);
$data = "5295760474330638";
$encryptedData = openssl_encrypt($data, "AES-128-CBC", $rawKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
echo base64_encode($rawKey); // CfOXpWTBF9mNcs7qSBw62OJpp+U/l/fu/YLh5aOXpXY=
echo base64_encode($iv); // 4mmn5T+X9+79guHlo5eldg==
echo base64_encode($encryptedData); // 3QQWLw7Q+Ff0Gz50XGsGORsOMWh9oeBiYprPr3/vl+I=
```

Javascript code:

```
encrypt () {
    const key = this.CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('CfOXpWTBF9mNcs7qSBw62OJpp+U/l/fu/YLh5aOXpXY=');
    const iv = this.CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('4mmn5T+X9+79guHlo5eldg==');
    const data = '5295760474330638';
    const encrypted: any = this.CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
      mode: this.CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      iv: iv
    });
    console.log(encrypted.ciphertext.toString(this.CryptoJS.enc.Base64)); 
    // QivkpDkujSt0JHAMwnENe6Qlkvgb8+3ddu7AcP401aM=
}
```

Why I'm getting diffrent outputs even though the key and iv are the same?

Comment: Just use AES-256-CBC in your PHP code. In the CryptoJS code a 32 bytes key and therefore AES-256 is applied. Both must also be used in the PHP code to produce the same ciphertext! Note: In contrast to the CryptoJS code, where the key length determines the AES variant (e.g. a 32 bytes key specifies AES-256), in the PHP code the AES variant must be specified _explicitly_ (e.g. AES-256-CBC). Too short keys are padded with 0 values, too long keys are simply truncated.

Comment: It works, thx @Topaco. BTW is it possible to not change PHP code and instead force AES-128 in Crypto js with this key?

Comment: Actually I already explained this: Since AES-128-CBC is specified in the PHP code, only the first 16 bytes of the 32 bytes key `$rawKey` are used for the actual key. As IV the last 16 bytes of `$rawKey` are applied. In the CryptoJS code, the same key and IV must be used, e.g. `const key2 = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(key.words.slice(0, 4));` and `const iv2 = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(key.words.slice(4, 4 + 4));`. Here, `key` is the already defined key (corresponding to `$rawKey`). Now use `key2` and `iv2` as key and IV for encryption, then you get the result of the PHP code.